# Error when trying to view SSRS Subscriptions in Report manager Url

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

Our report server database was moved to a new environment. Subscriptions work well with most users/owners. However, we have issues with one not working. changes were made with the query below:

```
      DECLARE @OldUserID uniqueidentifier
      DECLARE @NewUserID uniqueidentifier
      SELECT @OldUserID = UserID FROM dbo.Users WHERE UserName = 'DOMAINA\OldUser'
      SELECT @NewUserID = UserID FROM dbo.Users WHERE UserName = 'DOMAINA\NewUser'
      UPDATE dbo.Subscriptions SET OwnerID = @NewUserID WHERE OwnerID = @OldUserID
```

You can query(SSMS) and see that the new user now has the subscriptions but when you try to view this on the report server, we get the error as in the image below

[image]

And the log file error is like:

```html
library!ReportServer_0-1!2a1c!10/05/2017-11:53:22:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.NotEnabledException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.NotEnabledException: The requested functionality is not currently enabled.;
extensionfactory!ReportServer_0-1!2a1c!10/05/2017-11:53:22:: i INFO: Skipped instantiating Report Server PowerBI report server extension. Extension was not enabled.
library!ReportServer_0-1!2908!10/05/2017-11:53:29:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.NotEnabledException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.NotEnabledException: The requested functionality is not currently enabled.;
extensionfactory!ReportServer_0-1!2908!10/05/2017-11:53:29:: i INFO: Skipped instantiating Report Server PowerBI report server extension. Extension was not enabled.
library!ReportServer_0-1!2fa4!10/05/2017-11:53:29:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.NotEnabledException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.NotEnabledException: The requested functionality is not currently enabled.;
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Most likely some underlying table didn't get updated with the new user. Can you just recreate the subscription?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I went to ReportServer database [Subscriptions] table, & selected reports that were mine (using OwnerID, that you can look up in the [Users] table), & it appeared that some of my reports had 'en' locale, while others - 'rus'. When only one locale left, the problem has gone.

Here is the select you are looking for:

```
SELECT [SubscriptionID]
    ,[OwnerID]
    ,[Report_OID]
    ,[Locale]
    ,[InactiveFlags]
    ,[ExtensionSettings]
    ,[ModifiedByID]
    ,[ModifiedDate]
    ,[Description]
    ,[LastStatus]
    ,[EventType]
    ,[MatchData]
    ,[LastRunTime]
    ,[Parameters]
    ,[DataSettings]
    ,[DeliveryExtension]
    ,[Version]
    ,[ReportZone]
FROM [ReportServer].[dbo].[Subscriptions] s
inner join [ReportServer].[dbo].[Users] u
on s.ownerid = u.[UserID]
where u.username like '%your_name%'
```