# SSRS Delivery Extension not found

Tags: reporting-services, subscription, extensibility

I'm trying to develop a delivery extension for SSRS.
I created a dll with one class. The class implements both IExtension and IDeliveryExtension interfaces. I copied the built dll file (`MyExtension.dll`) to the report's server bin folder. It is not in default location, but it should not be a problem:

> D:\SSRS\MSRS13.MyInstanceName\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin

In rsreportserver.config I added this in Extensions/Delivery:

```
<Extensions>
        <Delivery>
            <Extension Name="My Extension" Type="My.Extensions.MyExtension,MyExtension" Visible="true" />
```

In rssrvpolicy.config I have something like this:

```
<CodeGroup class="UnionCodeGroup" version="1" PermissionSetName="FullTrust">
    <IMembershipCondition class="UrlMembershipCondition" version="1" Url="$CodeGen$/*" />
</CodeGroup>
<CodeGroup class="UnionCodeGroup" version="1" PermissionSetName="FullTrust" Name="MyCustomCodeGroup" Description="trying out delivery extension">
    <IMembershipCondition class="UrlMembershipCondition" version="1" Url="D:\SSRS\MSRS13.MyInstanceName\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin\MyExtension.dll" />
</CodeGroup>
```

I do not see the extension when I create a new subscription. In log I keep getting this error:

> *extensionfactory!ReportServer_0-1!155c!02/18/2019-17:34:56:: e ERROR: Exception caught instantiating My Extension report server extension:
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException:
>   Konfigurationsfehler beim Berichtsserver: . --->
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'MyExtension.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find
>   the file specified..
>   library!ReportServer_0-1!1c78!02/18/2019-17:34:56:: e ERROR: Throwing
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.NotEnabledException:
>   ,
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.NotEnabledException:
>   Die angeforderte Funktionalität ist zurzeit nicht aktiviert.;*

I added the MyExtension.dll to GAC and restarted report server. I granted full permissions for the dll file to the SSRS windows service account and verified the account can see it. Still no success...

What am I missing?

Comment: This could indicate that your custom extension class is referencing an assembly that is not deployed on that server.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint! I checked that - the assembly references only Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces.dll. This library is present in the bin folder of the report server.

Comment: Take a look at this answer. It has to do with multiple languages defined for reports in subscriptions or a language other than what is intended, perhaps this is similar? --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46563378/error-when-trying-to-view-ssrs-subscriptions-in-report-manager-url

Comment: Thanks for link, I'll check it. The servers locale is swiss german, so it definitely might have something to do with that.

Comment: I checked the link and it does not seem to be related. I wonder if the dll may need some resource file or something like that, and therefore it is not visible to the server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem, it was .NET framework version. My assembly was compiled for .NET Framework 4.6.1. **When I switched to .NET Framework 3.5, all worked fine.**

Here are details:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2869522/the-net-framework-4-x-assemblies-are-not-supported-in-sql-server-repor

> Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) supports extensions by including custom extensions and custom code. However, SSRS does not support Microsoft .NET Framework 4.x-based assemblies. Therefore, you cannot load a .NET Framework 4.x assembly.

There is another problem, because I cannot reference assemblies built with .NET Framework 4.x ...

Anyway, I hope this can help someone...